# ajax uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) never invoked

Tags: javascript, ajax

im sending mail with files and inputs from a FORM , i use ajax and everything works, its a long process so i wanted to add progressBar, the problem is:

uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) never invoked.

any ideas?

ajax:

```
    var options = { 
                        beforeSend: function() 
                        {
                            $("#progress").show();
                            //clear everything
                            $("#bar").width('0%');
                            $("#percent").html("0%");
                        },
                        uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) 
                        {
                            console.log("in uploadprogress");
                            console.log(total);
                            console.log(percentComplete);
                            $("#bar").width(percentComplete+'%');
                            $("#percent").html(percentComplete+'%');

                        },
                        success: function() 
                        {
                            alert('Form submitted'); 
                            $("#bar").width('100%');
                            $("#percent").html('100%');

                        },
                        error: function()
                        {
                            // The request failed - So do something here
                            alert('Form NOT submitted'); //display an alert   whether the form is
                            console.log('form not submited ERROR');

                        }

                    }; 

                         $("#myForm").ajaxForm(options);
```

i used console.log("in uploadprogress") and nothing is logged. also used alert but nothing shows up...

Comment: Maybe your browser doesn't support it? Try the [demo page](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/progress.html).

Comment: the browser support  it but thanx anyway, i maneged to find a work around using [link](https://github.com/hayageek/jquery-progress-bar) but not completly solved..still nedd to calc Content-Length for it to work